# Show only last comment from column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

below query showing all selected columns, but when in column tblAssetComments.Comment is more than one, it shows 3 rows with same asset, can someone help me/suggest what to use.

```
Select Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetID,
  tblAssets.AssetName,
  tblAssetComments.Comment,
  tblAssetComments.Added
From tblAssets
  Inner Join tblComputersystem On tblAssets.AssetID = tblComputersystem.AssetID
  Left Join tblAssetComments On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetComments.AssetID
Where tblAssets.AssetName Like 'c%' And tblComputersystem.Domainrole > 1 And
  tblComputersystem.SystemType Like 'x64%'
Order By tblAssets.AssetName
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh using MS SQL